# MySQL Query - Large Date Range Optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have the following MySQL query, and am looking for possible opportunities to improve the performance. Over smaller sate ranges (1-2 months) it uses the available indexes but when querying 12+ it scans the entire table and takes 10+ seconds (720k rows).

I have a BTREE index on "ordered_at, sales_channel_id" columns, which is used for the smaller queries. Would there be a more optimal index to use?

I hope the query obvious, but what i'm trying to achieve is a list of all orders for a specific "model_id" broken down by Year, Month Name, Week of the Month and a sum of item quantity.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    `inventory`.`model_id`,
    YEAR(`order_items`.ordered_at) AS Year,
    MONTHNAME(`order_items`.ordered_at) AS Month,
    CONCAT("Week ", FLOOR(((DAY(`order_items`.ordered_at) - 1) / 7) + 1)) AS Week,
    SUM(`order_items`.quantity) AS UnitsSold
FROM
    `order_items`
    JOIN `inventory` ON `inventory`.`sku` = `order_items`.`sku`
        AND `inventory`.`id` = (
            SELECT
                min(id)
            FROM
                inventory
        WHERE
            `inventory`.sku = `order_items`.sku)
    WHERE
        `order_items`.`ordered_at` BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-01 23:59:59'
        AND `order_items`.`sales_channel_id` in(1, 2, 3, 4)
    GROUP BY
        `order_items`.`model_id`, `Year`, month(`order_items`.ordered_at), `Month`, `Week`
    ORDER BY
        `order_items`.`model_id` ASC,
        `Year` ASC,
        month(`order_items`.ordered_at) ASC,
        `Month` ASC,
        `Week` ASC;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I've tried re-ordering the where clause and adding/removing possible indexes but the query still takes 10+ seconds over longer date ranges. I also need to run this for a YoY comparison so it essentially takes 20+ seconds to execute (plus data processing and report rendering time)

Comment: questions about performance must include always a EXPLAIN query and a CREATE TABLE and some sample data and wanted result. i still ty to figure out what the SELCT min(id) makes exactly and what the benefit is

Comment: You may try to use according index hint (USE INDEX or FORCE INDEX).

Answer (score 0):

Each of these prevents the use of `sku` in an index:

```
      AND  `order_items`.`sku` IS NOT NULL
      AND  `order_items`.`sku` != ''
```

Since the following are different, there will be an extra temp table and sort.  (`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` should show that.)

```
    GROUP BY  `model_id`, `Year`, month(ordered_at), `Month`,
        `Week`
    ORDER BY  `model_id` ASC, `Year` ASC, month(ordered_at) ASC,
        `Week` ASC
```

If I read it correctly, `Month` is effectively the same as `MONTH(ordered_at)`, hence could be removed form the `GROUP BY`.  If not, then add it *in the same position* to the `ORDER BY`.

(Please qualify all columns with which table they are in; I cannot suggest better indexes without knowing what is where.)  At least the following is needed:

```
order_items:  INDEX(SKU)
```

It looks like the `LEFT JOIN` is really `JOIN`, so change that.

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for your suggestions. Removing the empty SKU checks, matching the order/group clauses and changing to JOIN managed to reduce the execution time by a second or so. I have updated the query above with table names. Hopefully there might be a performance improvement somewhere as 720k records isn't that much.

Comment: @Rob - See if it works to _remove_ `MONTH(ordered_at)` from _both_ the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.